# R - linked matrices rows - make code faster

Tags: r, performance, matrix

Here is my dilemma:

- I am trying to price a physical asset to do this I need to simulate a lot of random paths.
- After each path is simulated I have to fill 26 equally sized matrices that are linked to not only the price paths but also to each other
- The problem I am having is that I am forced to go row by row in these matrices and this is really slowing down my code (13.33 seconds per simulation)
- What I mean by the matrices are linked is that if you have 2 matrices A and B that are already initialized (so the first rows are filled with initial values) row 2 of B is a function of row 1 of A, then row 2 of A is a function of row 2 of B, then row 3 of B is a function of row 2 of A so I can't fill be without filling A and vice versa.
- In reality the functions that link them are very very complex and the row of one matrix can be a function of the rows of up to 5 other matrices and the indices of the rows of these 5 matrices are not always as simple as row at index -1 and row at same index.
- I am finding myself forced go through all the matrices row by row to fill them all. So I am forced to fill row 2 of matrice B then row 2 of matrice A then row 3 of matrice B then row 3 of matrice A...

I will give the following reproducible example just to make it clear what I mean by linked together and what I am doing now. Please understand that on reality the functions are way more complex and so the links of the matrices between each other as well.

```
a <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
b <- matrix(c(2,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

function_fill_a <- function(a, b, r = 2){
  a[r, ] <- a[r,] + b[r, ]
  return(a)
}

function_fill_b <- function(a, b, r = 2){
  b[r, ] <- a[r-1,] + 2
  return(b)
}

for( i in 2:nrow(a)){
  b <- function_fill_b(a, b, i)
  a <- function_fill_a(a, b, i)
}
```

Is there a way to not be forced to use this for loop at the end because it is what is slowing down my code I am certain.

**EDIT - Reply to comments**

in my code this for loop is actually a function that takes a list of matrices and then it applies the functions on the matrices in the list.

so it looks like this:

```
m <- list("a" = a, "b"= b)

fill_all <- function(m){
    for( i in 2:nrow(m$a)){
      m$b <- function_fill_b(m$a, m$b, i)
      m$a <- function_fill_a(m$a, m$b, i)
    }
return(m)
    }

m <- fill_all(m)
```

If I use Rcpp will I have to rewrite all the functions or only this last one ? is there a way to call these functions written in R into the cppFunction ?

Comment: Most methods I can think of (that might capitalize on R's efficiencies when vectoring things) don't work due to the complex dependencies. Some thoughts: `Rcpp` for significant speed-ups; parallelization (if you have unconnected trees of matrices); general R speed-ups (BLAS, MKL); buy a faster computer (shrug).

Comment: The problem is similar to rolling window calculations (e.g., `zoo`), where there really is no way to vectorize it, since the vector is changing mid-step. (In my terms, "vectorizing" can be matrix/array-centric as well.) If this is a "production" thing, if `Rcpp` is daunting, you might consider other languages such as Python or Julia (though if `Rcpp` is scary and you aren't a language-phile, then learning Julia just for this might also be a bit steep).

Comment: You will get some minor efficiency gains if you transpose your matrices and use columns instead of rows. R stores matrices in column-major order so referencing/passing around values in a column is tiny bit quicker than a row. You also *might* get a speed boost by adapting your `function_fill_*` to take vectors and return vectors that get assigned the the matrix rather than passing the whole matrix through. Not sure, but might be worth testing...

Comment: However, you seem to be making a lot of unfounded assumptions. *"this for loop... it is what is slowing down my code I am certain"*. Why are you certain? Have you profiled your code? *"Please understand that on reality the functions are way more complex..."* My guess is that these "way more complex" functions eat up **much** more time than the surrounding `for` loop.

Comment: My guess is about 99% of your time is spent doing `function_fill_*`, and about 1% is left doing the rest. So if you work hard and convert everything else into Rcpp and speed it up 100x, you will save a little less than 1% of your overall runtime. Of course that's just a guess, but until you profile your code I think it is a good assumption. So, my recommendation would be (a) profile your code, then (b) target your improvements on the slow parts of your code. The [Profiling section of Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html) is a good place to start.